# Message: Undefined index: id

Tags: php, idiorm

I´ve my query

```
$proveedores = ORM::for_table('proveedor')->where_like('nombreproveedor',"%{$namesearch}%")->order_by_asc('nieproveedor')->find_many();
```

I want to save the id. I realize:

$_SESSION['idproveedor'] = $proveedores['id'];

My table structure is:

[image]

```
I get the following error in slim

Type: ErrorException
Code: 8
Message: Undefined index: id
```

the error get it in

$_SESSION['idproveedor']=$proveedores['id'];

var_dump($proveedores);die() output is:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=9)
      'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'nieproveedor' => string '11111111' (length=8)
      'nombreproveedor' => string 'Agrar Semillas S.A' (length=18)
      'direccion' => string 'Route de Saint Sever 
' (length=23)
      'telefono' => string ' 976470646' (length=10)
      'ciudad' => string '' (length=0)
      'region' => null
      'pais' => null
      'codpostal' => null
  1 => 
    array (size=9)
      'id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'nieproveedor' => string '22222222' (length=8)
      'nombreproveedor' => string 'Agrosa Semillas Selectas, S.A.' (length=30)
      'direccion' => string 'ddddsfwwffwwwwwwffwfw' (length=21)
      'telefono' => string ' 949 305226' (length=11)
      'ciudad' => string '' (length=0)
      'region' => null
      'pais' => null
      'codpostal' => null
```

Comment: post output of var_dump($proveedores); PLS

Comment: Not familiar with the library you're using, but your output looks like a two-dimensional array. So, $proveedores[0]['id'] would get you the first id, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your var dump `$proveedores` is an array with 2 elements which represent 2 rows in your table. 
The query that you issued seems to have returned 2 rows as a result to access them you should do something like the following

```
$id1 = $proveedores[0]['id'];
$id2 = $proveedores[1]['id'];
```